# Two Parallel multilined TextViews not lining up

Tags: android, textview, multiline

I have two textviews that are each a different language lined up side by side using weight_sum. However sometimes the verse (it's a bilingual parallel bible) is longer in one language than the other. This offsets the whole chapter. Is there any way to tell the textview (it is getting the data from a string) not to start the next verse (specifically line as I'm skipping two lines using \n\n in each verse) until both are finished? I was thinking maybe I could use an if statement using the x-axis.

Note: Each language of the chapter is in one string

Go here to see an image of the output https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1mKUWcpU8hkOXByZjlZN20tLWM/view?usp=sharing

You'll notice from the output that the alignment isn't correct

Comment: Your question is not making things clear, can you post any example?

Comment: a small illustration/picture would really help

Answer (score 1):

If you divide each verse into a 2 TextViews inside a Layout those Layout can be stacked to achieve your desired functionality.

```
------------------------  <LinearLayout>
| Verse 1  |  Verse 1b |  <Text View/>, <TextView/>
|   |      |     |     |
|   |      |     |     |
|          |     |     |
------------------------  </LinearLayout>
------------------------  <LinearLayout>
* Verse 2  *  Verse 2b *  <Text View/>, <TextView/>
*          *     |     *
etc...
```

This method also works if you choose to put these layout into a ListView to be able to scroll through the verses efficiently

Comment: thanks- the listview is really smart and would help with some visibility issues I'm having. How would I align the verses if I used a listview? Would I use a linear layout in the listview?

Comment: Yes each item in the ListView could contain a LinearLayout, but a Relative layout could be used just as effectively, the main idea should be to properly understand and use [ListViews](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)